# Power loss after driving over 15km (engine hot)

Tags: engine, coolant, head-gasket, vauxhall, motors

I have a 2010  Opel corsa D driven under 50k km. The car was parked outside for 5 weeks as I was in vacation (outside temperature -4deg to +6deg). As I came back I found a strange problem every time I drive more than 15-20km.

After stalling the engine after a 15-20km drive, when i start the engine again I’m facing severe power loss. There is absolutely no acceleration as I press the pedal. If I try to move the car front or reverse releasing the clutch slowly there is severe vibration. I checked the coolant- not boiling, coolant level is at right level, radiator fan normal, no check engine light, slight milky white substance under engine oil cap but I guess thats due to condensation. So I pulled over the car and waited like 20mins, engine cooled down and power back, accelerator works normal.

When I drive like 5-6km (normally) I never face this problem. I tried stalling the engine several times in short trips no issue with power.

Is the engine heating up too much? If so what could be the cause? Faulty radiator or the O2 sensor can go inefficient at high temperature?

I checked the temperature of the engine- cold start 12 deg, after 2 km 60 deg, after 5km 80 deg and after 9 km 105 deg. I didn’t stressed the engine more as I’m afraid I might blow the head gasket.

Note: problem only occurs after stalling the engine, I drove for about 40km at a stretch no issues. Once I stall for 5-10 mins and start again, no power.

Comment: Sounds like an Earthing issue - over the longer drive, the engine isn't getting enough current to earth, so it's building up a static charge - which can then cause weird issues. Look for a broken earth strap between the engine block and the chassis.

Comment: @PeteCon this explanation is new to me.

Comment: 109 Deg after 9km to me is worrying, also the milky substance under the oil cap is also worrying... When was the last time you replaced oil and coolant? Also by stalling the engine you mean switching off the engine, or the engine stops on its own?

Comment: @Alimba engine oil and filter was changed 4 months ago... ~2k km driven after oil/filter change. Coolant has been changed 2 years back.. ~20k km driven after coolant refill... the engine never stalls on its own.. driven about 40km in a stretch since the problem started... it only happens after stalling the engine manually and then starting after a few mins...

Answer (score 0):

i try with my knowledge.

if oil change to a bit white ( milky) that indicates the oil saturated with water (heavily humid area because snow could that reason why it have water in it)

try to to change your oil, dump away the old oil. add new oil, use oil specifically for your region (I'm in tropical so i just know oil 10sw) i don't know your oil spec from your region it could be that is the reason why heat up much, you use wrong oil engine.

there are several more reason for this.
1. your gear transmission it's damaged (very unlikely)

2. your brake is failed to open making the engine like trying to pull heavy load (usually your tire will be hot too check your tire after 6km try to sense it with your hand close to center of rim)  - this is the most problems
3. your water pump failed or clogged, making the engine hot but your radiator still cool. -.i have this one problematic.
4. if you drive petrol this could be your spark plug. check your spark plug, if your spark dark enough like carbon clean it, if black because oiled it could be your ring piston problem
5. the most dumb but it could be occurs because i have that one problem. you did put too much oil. if you put too much oil, the oil will comes up to piston chamber because heat and high pressure and making your spark plugs fueled by oil, and after a while your engine loss power because bad ignition